# How can I select individual lines in a SugarCRM Account address box?

Tags: java, sugarcrm

I am using Java to perform an integration with SugarCRM 6.5 .

I am pulling the address field from a SugarCRM `Account` and attempting to place that in one or two textboxes on a website.  I am checking its length to see if I need to split it across two fields on my website or if just one would suffice.  I have the basic functionality working.

My issue is that I am unable to detect line breaks (newlines?) in the `Account` which leads me to have the lines smooshed together instead of say, replacing the newline characters with a single whitespace.

Example:

```
4500 South 850 East
Broadway Lane SLC
UT, 84117 USA
```

is becoming:

```
4500 South 850 EastBroadway Lane
SLCUT, 84117 USA
```

...which is clearly not desirable on a professional website.

Is there a way to detect these newlines in SugarCRM 6.5? (Thank you!)

UPDATE: As requested, here is my parsing code:

```
public void setStreetAddress( String sAddress ) { 
    if( sAddress == null ) { return; }

    String trimmed = sAddress.trim().replaceAll( "[\\r\\n]", " ");

    if( trimmed.length() > 60 ){
        streetAddress = sAddress.trim().substring( 0, 60 );
        streetAddress2 = sAddress.trim().substring( 60 ); // 60 till end.
    }
    else{
        streetAddress = sAddress; 
        streetAddress2 = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to do this? Thanks!

Comment: There are several layers of abstraction involved in this process and passing data around.  The complete code would be largely irrelevant.  However, it is worth knowing that in my SugarCRM setup, the billing address street portion is listed in one field: `billing_address_street`.  I'll post the parsing code I've attempted in a second though.